# Alder Tree Root Nodule Origins?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I recently found out that alder trees have root nodules which contain nitrogen-fixing bacteria and that alders are primary colonizers in primary succession. That leads me to this question: since there are really no fungi in the soil and since the alder is a colonizing species, where does the fungi come from? Or is my assumption that there are no fungi in the soil incorrect?

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need any assistance, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Where did you hear that alder trees are primary colonizers? Primary colonizers tend to be organisms such as mosses and bryophytes. I don't know for sure, but I would be willing to bet good money that the fungi make it there long before the alder trees do

Comment: Cyanobacteria can form nodules in plants, and actinobacteria also called a sort of association which is called "actinorhyza" similar to mycorrhiza. But how could you conclude there is no fungi? fungi are everywhere, and they play a key-role in degradation of lignin etc biopolymers from plants

Comment: How you conclude that nodules contain nitrogen fixing bacteria? did you found that from experimental analysis?

Comment: Many types of bacteria can form nodules or such. In case of your alder tree root nodules; it might be some sort of Actinorhiza. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankia_alni , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_nodule , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinorhizal_plant.

Comment: Symbiotic bacteria and fungi can come to the plant in several ways. It can come through soil (where some-other forms of propagules already exists in soil). Or it can be remain attached at the surface of seeds (or other plant propagules) and plant-debris. Sometimes they can exist inside the plant's tissues and propagules in actively symbiotic form (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endophyte).

Answer (score 1):

Any soil microbiology textbook will tell you that there are a great number of fungi in most soils. I believe there are 12 or 13 species of non-legumes capable of fixing atmospheric nitrogen. Podocarpus is one of them. Look at the roots of podocarpus and you will see nodules all along the roots.